# How do I initialize a CMake variable with the result of a shell command

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to set a variable in a CMake script to the output of a shell command? 
Something like `SET(FOO COMMAND "echo bar")` would come to mind

Answer (score 113):

You want the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command.

In your case, on Windows:

```
execute_process(COMMAND CMD /c echo bar OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)
```

or on Linux, simply:

```
execute_process(COMMAND echo bar OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)
```

In this particular case, CMake offers a cross-platform solution.  CMake can itself be used to run commands that can be used on all systems, one of which is `echo`.  To do this, CMake should be passed the command line arg [`-E`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode).  For the full list of such commands, run `cmake -E help`

Inside a CMake script, the CMake executable is referred to by [`${CMAKE_COMMAND}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMMAND.html), so the script needs to do:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo bar OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO)
```

Comment: Depending on the command you execute, it may set trailing whitespaces to the variable. If this behaviour is not desirable, you can use the option OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE as the last argument to the 'execute_process' function.

Comment: @hbobenicio `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` is more or less **required** IMO

Comment: If your command is more than a simple program call, use `COMMAND bash "-c" "your_complex.sh | command && stuff"`. Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695350/5470596

Comment: This post was very helpful to me. I used it to set the python includes path to compile a pybind11 module using the actual python3 that should be compiled for, with 
```
execute_process(COMMAND python3-config --includes OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_INCLUDES OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE )
message("*** Set PYTHON_INCLUDES=${PYTHON_INCLUDES}")
```

Comment: Then later in CMakeLists.txt file, `target_compile_options(plane PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra ${PYTHON_INCLUDES})`