# CMake's execute_process and arbitrary shell scripts

Tags: shell, command-line, cmake

CMake's `execute_process` command seems to only let you, well, execute a process - not an arbitrary line you could feed a command shell. The thing is, I want to use pipes, file descriptor redirection, etc. - and that does not seem to be possible. The alternative would be very painful for me (I think)...

What should I do?

PS - CMake 2.8 and 3.x answer(s) are interesting.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can execute any shell script, using your shell's support for taking in a script within a string argument.

Example:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND bash "-c" "echo -n hello | sed 's/hello/world/;'" 
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE FOO
)
```

will result in `FOO` containing `world`.

Of course, you would need to escape quotes and backslashes with care. Also remember that running bash would only work on platforms which *have* bash - i.e. it won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 10):

1. `execute_process command seems to only let you, well, execute a process - not an arbitrary line you could feed a command shell.`

Yes, exactly this is written in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) for that command:

> All arguments are passed VERBATIM to the child process. No intermediate shell is used, so shell operators such as > are treated as normal arguments.

2. `I want to use pipes`

Different `COMMAND` within same `execute_process` invocation are actually piped:

> Runs the given sequence of one or more commands with the standard output of each process piped to the standard input of the next.

3. `file descriptor redirection, etc. - and that does not seem to be possible.`

For complex things just prepare **separate shell script** and run it using `execute_process`. You can pass variables from CMake to this script using its parameters, or with prelimiary `configure_file`.

Comment: I can't prepare a distinct shell script on a target machine which is not the development machine - or,  do you suggest I bundle this shell script as well? An extra file just for that?

Comment: I mean additional shell script in *sources*. If you perform build not on the target machine, you needn't to put this script there.

Comment: There is `INPUT_FILE` for file descriptor, you can put `/dev/null` as a file name for example.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to pipe two commands one after the other and actually learned that each `COMMAND` of the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) is piped already. So at least that much is resolved by simply adding commands one after the other:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND echo "Hello"
    COMMAND sed -e 's/H/h/'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GREETINGS
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
```

Now the variable `GREETINGS` is set to `hello`.

If you indeed need a lot of file redirection (as you stated), you probably want to write an external script and then execute that script from `CMakeLists.txt`. It's really difficult to get all the escaping right in CMake.

If you can simplify your scripts to one command generating a file, then another handling that file, etc. then you can always use the `INPUT_FILE` and `OUTPUT_FILE` options. Or pass a filename to your command for the input.

It's often much cleaner to handle one file at a time. Although I understand that some commands may need multiple sources and destinations.

Comment: What is the minimum CMake version with this piping capability?

Comment: @einpoklum From what I can see, it was already like that in [2.8.0](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.0/cmake.html#command:execute_process).