# CMake check '/etc/hosts' for RPM installation

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm trying to write a simple `execute_process` command for my `CMakeLists.txt` to check for the presence of a certain piece of text in the hosts file when the RPM is being installed, and if it isn't there, append it to the hosts file.

However, when running CMake, I get the message:

```
grep ||: No such file or directory
grep: echo: No such file or directory
grep: 172.16.10.43 UPSSERVER: No such file or directory
grep: >>: No such file or directory
```

It seems to think each piece of my executed command is a file? Here is the command in question:

```
set(HOSTS_UPSSERVER "172.16.10.43 UPSSERVER")
execute_process(COMMAND grep -qxF ${HOSTS_UPSSERVER} /etc/hosts || echo ${HOSTS_UPSSERVER} >> /etc/hosts)
```

I know the command itself works because I've tested it on its own outside the command line. Is there an error in the syntax for the way I've defined the HOSTS_UPSSERVER variable? Or in the way I'm using the execute_process command?

I haven't had much luck finding useful information on CMake, as the documentation is vague and good tutorials are practically non-existent.

Comment: "... as the documentation is vague ..." - Eh? The documentation for [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html) **clearly states**, that in `COMMAND` arguments: "... shell operators such as `>` are treated as normal arguments. (Use the `INPUT_*`, `OUTPUT_*`, and `ERROR_*` options to redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr.)". See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689501/cmakes-execute-process-and-arbitrary-shell-scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the `/etc/hosts` from within cmake makes no sense as you would only check the file on your build host. To run a script during RPM install you need to include the code in the RPM itself by providing a spec file. During generation of the RPM via cpack you can configure a spec file via [CPACK_RPM_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackRPM.html)

Within the spec file you have to define several parameters as package name and dependencies. To run a script after installation you need to add it to the `%post` section:

```
%post
grep -qxF ${HOSTS_UPSSERVER} /etc/hosts || echo ${HOSTS_UPSSERVER} >> /etc/hosts
```

To use cmake variables within the spec file you need to generate it using `configure_file`.

Comment: Ah, I have a postinstall script already. I still don't understand how any of this works and am making it all up as I go. I'll put it in my postinstall script, then.