# CMake executing_process with bash pipeline

Tags: bash, cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I need to execute the mapping_string.sh script located under /include/ff. This script needs the user to type "y" in order to continue.

I tried this approach but I only get an infinite print of a "mapping_string.sh" string.

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND yes | bash mapping_string.sh
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ff
    RESULT_VARIABLE FF_MS_RES
)
```

Comment: As explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689501/cmakes-execute-process-and-arbitrary-shell-scripts) you need to run bash "-c" "your script"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> with bash pipeline

I.e. pipeline is part of Bash, you have to run Bash, not something else.

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND bash -c "yes | bash mapping_string.sh"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ff
    RESULT_VARIABLE FF_MS_RES
)
```

Make sure to read about quoting in CMake https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument .

Answer (score 5):

Use the functionality built in to the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command instead of the pipe:

> Commands are executed concurrently as a pipeline, with the standard output of each process piped to the standard input of the next. A single standard error pipe is used for all processes.

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND yes
    COMMAND bash mapping_string.sh
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ff
    RESULT_VARIABLE FF_MS_RES
)
```