# cmake execute_process does not capture standard output for git rev-parse

Tags: git, cmake

I am trying to get the short hash of `HEAD` within a simple `CMakeLists.txt`
The `execute_process` command fails to capture the stdout, however:

```
execute_process(COMMAND git rev-parse --short HEAD 
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_OUT
                RESULT_VARIABLE VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_RESULT 
                ERROR_VARIABLE VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_ERR
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

message("${VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_OUT}")
message("${VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_RESULT}")
message("${VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_ERR}")
```

`VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_OUT` and `VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_ERR` are both empty, `VERSION_BUILD_NUMBER_RESULT` states 0 (as expected). The command itself prints `9e8bdb3b1` to the console so it seems to working internally. Setting `OUTPUT_QUIET` doesn't help either. What can I do to capture the stdout correctly?

Comment: I use basically the same `execute_process` call to gather version information from git in my projects (the only difference is that I also use `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` and the name of the variables), and for me it works fine. Which version of CMake are you using?

Comment: `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` does the trick! Thanks a ton!

Comment: [Related (see comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13037230/1256452)